# Trying to print numbers in list without bracket and commas in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to print numbers from a list in series without the "[]" and the ",".
For example I have this code.

```
Bucket = [[] for i in range(2)]
result = []
for i in Bucket[::-1]:
    for j in i:
        result.append(j)

print result
```

Here Bucket has the value:

```
[[2, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
```

And the result has value:

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

I want the value of result to be printed as:

```
1 3 5 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to do it:

```
' '.join(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work

```
print " ".join(map(str,your_list))
```

The values of your list must be string not integer so map() is used to convert the list's value to string and now your able to use " ".join()

Comment: What's with the `lambda x:str(x)`? - You can directly use `str` there.

Comment: Thank you! The code worked but I don't get what the lambda does. Can you explain?

Comment: as suggest by @JonClements you can use directly map(str,your_list) i totally forgot:). 
However lambda are anonymous function , and to have a better insight i suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful